# how to Add “View More” and view less at the end of label after 3 lines

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have label with 10 lines of data in it but need to show only 3 line after that need to add view more button and after expanding view less , how to add it in xamarin form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you can use custom control to do this.

Firstly, you need to create contentview, name LargeTextLabel.xaml.

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label
            x:Name="SmallLabel"
            BackgroundColor="Beige"
            HeightRequest="50"
            IsVisible="true" />
        <Label
            x:Name="FullLabel"
            BackgroundColor="BurlyWood"
            HeightRequest="200"
            IsVisible="false" />
        <Button x:Name="ExpandContractButton" Text="See More" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Then create BindableProperty by code behind.

```
public partial class LargeTextLabel : ContentView
{
    public LargeTextLabel ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ExpandedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(LargeTextLabel),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ContentView),
        false,
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            if (newValue != null && bindable is LargeTextLabel control)
            {
                var actualNewValue = (bool)newValue;
                control.SmallLabel.IsVisible = !actualNewValue;
                control.FullLabel.IsVisible = actualNewValue;
                control.ExpandContractButton.Text = actualNewValue ? "See Less" : "See More";
            }
        });

    public bool Expanded { get; set; }



    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(LargeTextLabel),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ContentView),
        default(string),
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            if (newValue != null && bindable is LargeTextLabel control)
            {
                var actualNewValue = (string)newValue;
                control.SmallLabel.Text = actualNewValue;
                control.FullLabel.Text = actualNewValue;
            }
        });

    public string Text { get; set; }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                    nameof(LargeTextLabel),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ContentView),
        default(Command),
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            if (newValue != null && bindable is LargeTextLabel control)
            {
                var actualNewValue = (ICommand)newValue;
                control.ExpandContractButton.Command = actualNewValue;
            }
        });

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can use this custom control in your page.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:LargeTextLabel
            Command="{Binding ExpandContractCommand}"
            Expanded="{Binding TextExpanded}"
            Text="{Binding LabelText}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Create some property to bind this custom control, please implement INotifyPropertychanged to notify value update.

```
public partial class Page3 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _LabelText;
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return _LabelText; }
        set
        {
            _LabelText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LabelText");

        }
    }
    private ICommand _ExpandContractCommand;
    private bool _TextExpanded;

    public bool TextExpanded
    {
        get { return _TextExpanded; }
        set
        {
            _TextExpanded = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextExpanded");
        }
    }
    public Page3 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        LabelText = "Can any one help me on this?\nI want set read more option for multiline text end of label when i click on that read more it will expand or navigate to the any other page. Please help me on this .\n\nThanks in advance.";

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public ICommand ExpandContractCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ExpandContractCommand == null)
            {
                _ExpandContractCommand = new Command(() => {
                    TextExpanded = !TextExpanded;
                });
            }

            return _ExpandContractCommand;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Type local:LargeTextLabel not found .

Comment: i added like this,xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName"

Comment: @Mayuri, I have upload the sample at github: https://github.com/CherryBu/largelabel, please download it and try to test it. Please remember to mark my reply as answer if my reply solve your issue, thanks.

Comment: hi,its not working for me ,i have listview in that messages are their i want to add more on if message lable has more than 5 lines .otherwise i dont want to show more button

Comment: currently more button is adding to each and every label and its not clickable also to exapand @Cherry Bu -MSFT

Comment: can u help me on this scenario