# Xamarin.Forms. Detect text overlap

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good morning

I am struggling with detection if label`s text is higher than container. I tried to find some already done solution but couldn't find anything. Before I would start to implement some runtime solution in code behind I decided to ask you if I missed some knowledge.

I have and CarouselView which custom DataTemplate as below:

```
                      <Frame BorderColor="DarkGray"
                       CornerRadius="9"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Feed.Title}" 
                                       TextColor="Black" 
                                       FontSize="Title" 
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Image MinimumHeightRequest="200"
                                       MinimumWidthRequest="200">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <UriImageSource CachingEnabled="true"
                                                        Uri="{Binding Feed.ImageSource.AbsoluteUri}"
                                                        CacheValidity="1"/>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <Label 
                                                        Text="{Binding Feed.Description}" 
                                                        TextColor="Gray"
                                                        FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

When second label`s text is big it get sank in parent view as on picture:

[image]

As the solution I would like to remove not cut / not visible text and add three dots.
Is there any done solution or I should try to do runtime height measurements?

Thanks!

Comment: have you read the docs on truncation and wrapping?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#truncation-and-wrapping

Comment: hey, yes I did try all options, none works

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it isn't correctly determining the available height.

**ATTEMPT FIX #1:**

Does it do better if use `Grid` instead of `StackLayout`?

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*">
    <Label Grid.Row="0" ... />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" ... />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" ... />
</Grid>
```

Note the use of`*` for Row 2. This should tell Xamarin layout to use exactly the remaining height.

And "TailTruncation" for the ellipsis.

---

Also, I'm curious if it works better if you remove the surrounding `<Frame>`. If it does work better without that, then its a bug in nested layout.

---

**ATTEMPT FIX #2:**

Move Frame outside of CarouselView.

Then hopefully rest of the text can be seen by vertically-scrolling CarouselView. (Instead of using "...").

```
<Frame ...>
    <CarouselView ...>
        <DataTemplate ...>
            <StackLayout>
                ...
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Unfortuneatly with Grid it works the same

Comment: @miechooy - I've added a second approach to try.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way is to create a custom control to show the determined number of rows and show the three dots when you do not want to show the text which hided.

Xaml:

```
 <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="LabelContent" MaxLines="4"></Label>
        <Label Text="..."></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Code hehind:

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : ContentView
{

    public CustomControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
             nameof(Text),
             typeof(string),
             typeof(CustomControl1),
             string.Empty,
             propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
             {
                 var control = bindable as CustomControl1;
                 //var changingFrom = oldValue as string;
                 //var changingTo = newValue as string;
                 control.LabelContent.Text = newValue.ToString();
             });
}
```

Usage:

```
 <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding feeds}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame BorderColor="DarkGray"
                   CornerRadius="9"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                   TextColor="Black" 
                                   FontSize="Title" 
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image MinimumHeightRequest="200" Source="{Binding  ImageSource}"
                                   MinimumWidthRequest="200">

                        </Image>
                        <local:CustomControl1 Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

[image]

You could create a custom control LargeLabel to show the hidden text as well when you create the three dots. You could check the link for more details. [how to Add “View More” and view less at the end of label after 3 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157636/how-to-add-view-more-and-view-less-at-the-end-of-label-after-3-lines/58161127#58161127)

Comment: Hi, thank for an answer. The problem is that I dont know which is correct value for MaxLines in runtime.

Comment: It does not matter. If i have two lines text of the Label with the MaxLine 4, it would show two lines text and show three dots in the third. If you want to get the lines at runtime, it needs to calculate the lines via getting the width of each char and the width of the screen. It is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

not tested you code but logically it seems like it's issue because of Frame. as there is no Frame height for Frame if content is big how it will expand to that level?

another scenario, if you need to keep frame height same than child control should have scrollview where user can scroll. isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I tried solution with ScrollView however my CarouselView is scrolling vertically and I didnt find ScrollView work in this configuration

Comment: *"... as there is no Frame height for Frame ..."*. Xamarin's layout logic determines a height for Frame. In the question, the Frame is a good height (the size of CarouselView), but there appears to be a bug in how Xamarin handles multi-line label WordWrap modes, in this situation.